# How to get hypsometric curve from elevation data?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster

I have my elevation data but cannot  make an attribute table from it and so I'm not sure how to get any of that data into a table in order to make a hypsometric curve.

Answer (score 10):

The raster is stored in floating point format as individual values in each cell; therefore it has no attribute table.  An effective solution is to discretize the values and convert them to integer format.  This creates an attribute table which, when plotted, will yield a histogram.  Its cumulative sums are the hypsometric curve.

[image: DEM in relief]

The appearance of the hypsometric curve (in CDF form) for this sample DEM (a portion of Illinois available at http://exampledata.wolfram.com/ArcGRID.zip) varies with the fineness of the value discretization.  The following images use bins of 5, 1, and 1/5 meters, respectively.  As you can see, one can obtain a precise curve using moderately coarse bins.

[image: Hypsometric curves]

Discretizing a grid involves two operations which can be done in one step: divide by the bin width and truncate (or round, if you prefer).  For example, elevations in meters can be discretized into 0.1 meter increments via division by 0.1 followed by truncation, as in

```
Int( [elevation] / 0.1 )
```

This syntax, or something quite close to it, would be used in almost any version of ArcGIS (and in many other raster GISes as well).

Comment: If elevations can be both positive and negative, see whether your version of ArcGIS supports a `Floor` function, because some `Int` implementations truncate *towards 0* rather than downward, which would double the width of the bin containing 0 (an undesirable result).

Comment: Programmatically the histogram can be accessed from [IRasterBand.Histogram](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/Histogram_Property/001q0000025n000000/).  Would running this histogram through an accumulation process be valid?  The histogram is typically generated based on a specified sampling rate.

Comment: @Kirk That's a good idea, but my experience with ESRI software and statistical calculations leads me to mistrust it.  Where's the detailed documentation? E.g., exactly what kind of sampling procedure is used?  Where's the evidence that it gets the right result?  And if there is such evidence--say, through extensive user testing and reverse-engineering--we have to throw it all away and start over with the very next software patch.

Comment: Well, I was going to suggest plugging in your own [IBinFunction2](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/IBinFunction2_Interface/001q0000009n000000/), but I see it says "This interface is not intended to use by outside developers."  Oh well.

Comment: I would echo @whuber; ESRI's statistics are suspect. We have been complaining to tech support for two years that their percentiles/quartiles are being calculated incorrectly and are not even consistent within the software. We have empirically demonstrated to them that they are not "exact" nor "interpolated". Their response is that they are "sampling the data" but, will not reveal details.

Comment: @Jeffrey I met with ESRI representatives in 2006 and presented this issue (among many others) to them. At the time I had documented three different calculations of standard deviations within ArcGIS, of which at least one was clearly a bug.  I like and use ArcGIS for its strengths, but because of this kind of behavior I am compelled to conclude that statistical analysis--of any kind--is not among them.

Answer (score 5):

I normally use R for this. You can read GDAL raster data sets using `rgdal` (from CRAN), then build an empirical cumulative distribution for the elevation values using `ecdf` (built-in).

For example, I have my DEM in a GeoTIFF file, in R use:

```
library(rgdal)
topo <- readGDAL("mytoporaster.tif")
plot(ecdf(topo$band1), main="Hypsometric curve", xlab="Elevation (m)")
```

[image: hypsometric curve]

Comment: +1 Good solution.  You can analyze that curve (extensively) in R, too.

Answer (score 1):

[image: hypsometric curve]

Also see the tutorial at [Carleton](https://serc.carleton.edu/mathyouneed/hypsometric/hypsocurvesp.html).

Comment: This illustration reminds us there are (at least) *three* different ideas of "hypsometric curve."  According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypsometric_curve) it is an empirical CDF of elevations.  According to this illustration, it is the *complementary* CDF.  And according to [other references](http://comp.uark.edu/~sboss/study1s02.htm), it is a histogram (empirical PDF).

Answer (score 0):

I came across this paper that talks about a 9.x ArcGIS extension.

[CalHypso: An ArcGIS extension to calculate hypsometric curves and their statistical moments. Applications to drainage basin analysis in SE Spain](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.cageo.2008.06.006)

The extension with sample data is provided at [this download location](https://www.iamg.org/documents/oldftp/VOL35/v35-06-16.zip).

For the record the extension works in ArcGIS 10.4.1.

Comment: I glanced at the code to see how well it might work.  I stopped as soon as I hit the bubblesort implementation--no need to read any further.

Answer (score 0):

I just started using the HypsoLoop function in RStudio. It can even do sub-basin hypsometric curves.

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/hypsoLoop/index.html

[image]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).